# Angular file upload include file with other data in same post

Tags: angular, file-upload

Is it somehow possible to include a file together with other data in the same post?

```
export class ProfileExtraData {
    public id: number;
    public fullName: string;
    public file: any
}

return this.httpClient.post<void>(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/save`, profileExtraData);
```

When I try to do like above it is missing the image data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FormData to send file with other data via he same post request:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id',profileExtraData.id);
formData.append('fullName', profileExtraData.fullName);
formData.append('file', profileExtraData.file);

return this.httpClient.post<void>(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/save`, formData);
```

Please note that might require changes in your API endpoint too (request content type is no longer a 'json'. It becomes 'multipart/form-data' with FormData instance passed as 2nd argument to post method)